# I want fetch records on flow by invocable apex method

Tags: apex, invocable-method, method-invocation

i have to fetch records by apex because in get records components its hitting the limit
i want account records where parentID is null and website contains 'webdom' ,webdom its a formula varible which contains the output of formula means if we have website [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) then the value in the webdom is google

here is the code snippet

```
public class getAccountRecords {
 @InvocableMethod(label='Get Account Names' description='Returns 
 the list of account' category='Account')
 public static List<Account> getAccount(List<ID> ids) {
  list<string> webName = new list <string>();
    List<Account> con = [select Id ,Name, Website from Account 
  Where (Website like'webName') and ParentId = Null];
    return Con;
 }
 }
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want something like `WHERE Website LIKE '%.webName.%' AND ParentId = NULL`.

Comment: yess

@Felix van Hove

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. As there is no use of Ids, I have removed it from param.

```
@InvocableMethod(label='Get Account Names' description='Returns the list of account' category='Account')
public static List<Account> getAccount() {
    String webName = '%google%';
    List<Account> accnt= [SELECT Id ,Name, Website from Account WHERE Website LIKE:webName AND ParentId = Null];
    return accnt;
}
```

Comment: Actually google is just the example , i have  a formula where we have any website name , its just form who convert website value into single word ,how can we achieve this 

@Sunit Kumar Samanta

Comment: I have to put the value of formula which i get in the flow and by getting the website formula value i have to pass it into the query so i can found those records

Comment: invocable needs to be bulkified - each flow interview could pass a different domain and hence the results need to be apportioned by matching domain.

Comment: @user123713 You can pass the website name via parameter and using your formula you can easily achieve the webName variable value